# Oracle APEX 5 Button dynamic action

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Respective All!
Environment: APEX 5
What kind of expression I can write in "Condition" box of Dynamic Action I want to fire when button clicked? What should it be? SQL, PL/SQL, JavaScript or something else?
I mean first "Condition" field, just under Button name select list.
[image]

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Occasionally discovered that I can put JavaScript conditional expression inside...Like a if($v('P_MY_ITEM') !=="". What about other possibilities? SQL? PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Conditions allows us to control what happens when a condition is met (true actions) and what happens when the condition is not met (false actions.)

For example if you want to hide or show an item only when a certain value is met, you can choose e.g 'equal to or not equal to' condition based on a return value as defined in your select list.

Answer (score 0):

On the picture below is my example.

I have a button which refreshes table (interactive report). I created dynamic action to that button and added True action with parameters:

Action - Refresh
Select type - Region (my table is an interactive report)
Region - Kontrola (the name of my table as interactive report)

[image]